Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child even if i'm passing down a string
i'm building the frontend of an app using React.
There's an error however that i'm losing my mind over.
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {params, searchParams}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

the problem is that i'm passing to the othher components in the props a String as you can see down in the code:
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
 import Checkout from "../Checkout/page";


export function Model({object}:{object: Object}){
let arrayFromObj: any[] = []
arrayFromObj = Object.values(object);
const router = useRouter();
function handleClick(){
    router.push('/Checkout');
    let string: string = arrayFromObj[0];

    
    
    Checkout(string);
}

return(
    <div className="containerModal" id="modal">
        <center>
            <img src={arrayFromObj[1]} alt={arrayFromObj[0]} style={{border: "1px solid white", boxShadow: "0 0 15px #fff"}}></img>
            <h1>{arrayFromObj[1]}</h1>
            <p>Descrizione: {arrayFromObj[4]}</p>
            <p>Prezzo: {arrayFromObj[3]}</p>
            <p>Proprietario: {arrayFromObj[5]}</p>
            <p>Caricato il: {arrayFromObj[2]}</p>
            <p>Disponibilità: {arrayFromObj[6]}</p>
        </center>
        <button type="button" className="button" id="button" onClick={handleClick}>
            Acquista questo prodotto
        </button>
    </div>
)
}

this is the child component code:
import React from "react";

const Checkout = (name: string)=>{
     return <h1>{name}</h1>
 }
 export default Checkout

What am i doing wrong? Why am i getting this error?

What are you trying to do with Checkout component? It's component, and it supposed to be rendered within JSX, not within the click handler. Also in React, props are passed as an object by default, so name prop of Checkout in your case it's an object.

So on click the user should go the route of Checkout and i also need to pass data to the component. How do i do that?

So you can simply pass the necessary params with router.push. See, for example, this question.

Before you move on, please read some documentation and to few hello world projects. Seems, that you need to fill the gap in understanding how react works in general.

Thank you, however i've already solved that.
